# cordova plugin audiorecorder full_path not working in html5 audio

Tags: cordova

I am working with cordova app where i have implemented

> cordova-plugin-audiorecorder

Plugin is working fine for the recording and return the full_path of the file.

> Sample path :
>   "/data/user/0/io.cordova.myapp12313/files/audioRecords/temps_41.m4a"

When i set the 'src' of audio element, its not working. I asume it should work as source is valid. I am missing something?

I there some path scheme i must follow? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by  `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` and `FileReader` so that i can use `reader.readAsDataURL()` to use the url in `<Audio src="">`

**Code**

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
    function (fileSystem) {
      var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(
        successCallback,
        errCallback
      );
    }, errCallback
  );
```